# List all the optional arguments of a particular command in bash

Tags: command-line, bash

I was wondering if there was a way to find out all the optional arguments of a command in bash without having to open the man page and go through a lot of unwanted info.

```
Eg:
Input: <some_command> cat
Output: -A, --show-all           equivalent to -vET
  -b, --number-nonblank    number nonempty output lines, overrides -n
  -e                       equivalent to -vE
  -E, --show-ends          display $ at end of each line
  -n, --number             number all output lines
  -s, --squeeze-blank      suppress repeated empty output lines
  -t                       equivalent to -vT
  -T, --show-tabs          display TAB characters as ^I
  -u                       (ignored)
  -v, --show-nonprinting   use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit
```

Comment: Depends on how extensive the help is written. The help command is almost always shorter with complex commands such as bash (extreme example bit gets point across)

Comment: there is a command/tool which lists the most-used (from memory) options and provides a brief summary of the `man` page, but i forget what it is.  i know it was provided on the ubuntu podcast (for the UK LoCo) in the 'command line love' section, but no idea how long ago (last 1.5-3 years) (let alone being written about on many blogs).  it also may not have been installed by default for ubuntu.

Comment: This is one of the things I like about PowerShell. In the traditional Unix system, there are multiple redundant copies of the description of a utility's syntax: there is the commandline parser inside the utility itself, the output of `-h`, the man page, and the various commandline completion scripts for the various shells. In PowerShell, a cmdlet declares its syntax to the system *once*, and everything else (tab completion, even with dropdown menu, short help, long help, even syntax highlighting in the PowerShell IDE) is provided by the *shell* as a service.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's by no means universal, but many commands provide a *usage summary* in response to a `-h` or `--help` argument e.g.

```
$ cat --help
Usage: cat [OPTION]... [FILE]...
Concatenate FILE(s) to standard output.

With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

  -A, --show-all           equivalent to -vET
  -b, --number-nonblank    number nonempty output lines, overrides -n
  -e                       equivalent to -vE
  -E, --show-ends          display $ at end of each line
  -n, --number             number all output lines
  -s, --squeeze-blank      suppress repeated empty output lines
  -t                       equivalent to -vT
  -T, --show-tabs          display TAB characters as ^I
  -u                       (ignored)
  -v, --show-nonprinting   use ^ and M- notation, except for LFD and TAB
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

Examples:
  cat f - g  Output f's contents, then standard input, then g's contents.
  cat        Copy standard input to standard output.

GNU coreutils online help: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
Full documentation at: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/cat>
or available locally via: info '(coreutils) cat invocation'
```

Comment: the `--help` assumes its a GNU command; if from a bsd/unix background a `-h` is more commonly help, so can need two tries.

Comment: In some cases, although `--help` is an invalid option, the usage returns the options anyway. For instance, `lspci --help`

Answer (score 6):

The best approach depends on what kind of command you are running. You can try `-h` or `--help` as [steeldriver suggests](https://askubuntu.com/a/967214/22949), though for some commands that may not show *all* available options. *Ideally*, all options would be shown; even then, though, they might not all be explained. Official documentation, such as a [`man`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/man.1.html) or [`info`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/info.1.html) page, will usually show and explain all options--or at least all of them that the developers expect users to actually use. (Undocumented options do sometimes exist.)

First I recommend checking whether the command is an [*external command*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CommandsAndArguments#Executables) or a [*shell builtin*](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CommandsAndArguments#Builtins). You can do this with the `type` command. In [`bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/bash.1.html), you can pass the `-a` flag to the `type` command, to show what *would* run if the first match didn't exist:

```
ek@Io:~$ type -a ls
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
ls is /bin/ls
```

For me (and probably you), `ls` is an alias. Alias expansion is nonrecursive, so the `ls` in `ls --color=auto` doesn't use the alias, but uses the second listing, `/bin/ls`, instead. This is [a path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) to an [executable file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable), and thus an external command.

Therefore, to view documentation on [`ls`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ls.1.html) including all available options, **I would run `man ls`.**

Some cases, like [`cat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/cat.1.html), are simple:

```
ek@Io:~$ type -a cat
cat is /bin/cat
```

Commands that are built into the shell don't usually have their own manual pages, but you can use the `help` builtin to learn about them:

```
ek@Io:~$ type -a history
history is a shell builtin
ek@Io:~$ type -a help
help is a shell builtin
```

Thus you can run `help history` to learn about `history` or `help help` to learn about `help`.

For some builtins, like `compgen`, the `help` builtin shows you all their options, but it doesn't explain most of them. Whenever you need more information about a shell builtin, you can consult the manual page for `bash` (`man bash`), or you can consult the longer and more complete documentation by running `info bash` or [visiting it online](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/). You may find [the section on builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands) especially useful.

Some commands are available both as external executables *and* as shell builtins, which is another reason using `type -a` first can be helpful:

```
ek@Io:~$ type -a printf
printf is a shell builtin
printf is /usr/bin/printf
```

If you run `man printf`, for example, you will not be shown any information about the `-v` option, because `/usr/bin/printf` does not support it. The `bash` shell builtin does, though, and the text shown when you run `help printf` lists and explains it.

Finally, for manpages, it's useful to know that [you can read them online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/).